# WordPress - Use variable outside the loop

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

After updating my loop to get everything I want with this code:

```
<?php
$json = "";
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        global $wpdb;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ". $wpdb->prefix ."options WHERE option_id = 1";
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        if ($results){
            $json .= json_encode($results);
        }
    }
}
echo $json;
?>
```

I want to use the $json on the main page with js but I dont know how to get the variable.

Thank you in advace!

Comment: Are you running this on a page or a post? What values are being retrieved for which you need to manually write an SQL query for?

Comment: this script is ran in the index.php loop. I retrieve the database products to get them into a js function in the functions.php file.

Comment: Are the products a custom post type?

Comment: I dont know what that means, they are from woocomerence. Sry but I am a beginer.

Comment: That's okay. Custom post types are, like the name suggests, types of posts (pages, posts, comments, products) which are non-standard to WordPress. Like created by you or me in our theme, or by a plugin. WooCommerce products are also a post type. My question now is, are you trying to get the products from WooCommerce so you can use them in your JavaScript file?

Comment: yes, the code above retrieves what i need but i dont know how to get in the functions.php file where I have the js function in the header of every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "WordPress way" of making PHP values available to JavaScript is by *enqueuing* scripts and using [`wp_add_inline_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/).

In your `functions.php` add an action hook for `wp_enqueue_scripts`. This hook is executed whenever scripts should be placed in the HTML.

In this hook you can *register* and *enqueue* scripts. That means we specify the files we need, and any dependency they have, for example jQuery, and couple an inline script with the PHP values to the JS file where we need the JSON in.

```php
// Place me anywhere in functions.php.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
  // Get all the products.
  $products = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'numberposts' => -1,
  ) );
  
  // Turn the products into a JSON string.
  $products_json = json_encode( $products );
  
  // Register your script.
  // Check if the path to your JS file is correct.
  // get_theme_file_uri looks relative to the style.css file.
  wp_register_script( 'products', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/products.js' ), [], '1.0.0', true );

  // Add the inline script where the PHP data is turned into JavaScript.
  wp_add_inline_script( 'products', "window.__products__ = $products_json", 'before' ); 

  // Place both scripts in the HTML.
  wp_enqueue_script( 'products' );
} );
```

Now this specific function outputs an inline script `<script>...</script>` before a script with `<script id="products-js" src="https://yoursite/path-to-script/main.js"></script>`

The inline script creates a property on the `window` object which can be accessed from any file (as long as the file comes after the creation of the property).

```js
// products.js file.
var products = window.__products__;
console.log(products);
```

Comment: which part of this gets me the $json form the aforementioned index.php loop, or I dont need it anymore?

Comment: The aforementioned loop in the `index.php` file can be omitted. Though I would recommend that you would check if the value of `$products` is exactly what you're looking for. WP has a lot of helper functions and you will rarely need to write your own SQL queries, except if there is no existing way of getting what you need from the DB. But `get_posts()` will get an array of `WP_Post` objects, which contain every piece of information of each product. You can make the query of `get_posts()` more specific when needed.

Comment: it seems that the page outputs only white. Odd

Comment: The WSOD (White Screen Of Death) indicates that there is a fatal error in the PHP code. Make sure the PHP is inside of `<?php` and `?>` in your `functions.php` file. If that's not it, comment everything inside of the `function() {}` block out and reactive everything piece by piece until the code breaks again. Then we'll know more. Oh, and go to your `wp-config.php` and enable debuggin by setting `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`. This line is probably already in that file, but with the value `false`. Change it to `true`.

Comment: My apologies. There was a space between the double underscore and `products`. Please try the example again.